# Issue with icons in iOS 11 using cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9

Scenario:

- Xcode 9 and iOS 11 SDK.
- Cocoapods version 1.3.1
- Project with multiple targets

When I run my app on simulator or device with iOS 11 the app icon seams like unset, but of course it was setted in Assets.xcassets -> AppIcon.appiconset and works perfectly in iOS<=10.3.3.

[image: This is the result]

Can someone help me with this issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They added one more app icon size in new XCode, try to add that resolution and then check it out. I think it is 1024*1024.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have already added the AppStore icon, this is not the solution. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced the same issue in my Project ...
I have tried so many ways to solve it  ....
Finally I solved it for me like this ----

I `remove` all the iCon from `Assets.xcassets -> AppIcon.appiconset`
After that from `X-code` `menu bar` selecte `Product-->Clean` 
And `delete` the app from `Simulator` ..

Again add the all the iCon in `Assets.xcassets -> AppIcon.appiconset`
Run it ,,, and iCon is showing on the screen ... May it will help you.

Comment: Try by using delete Driveddata and force quit X-code and Restart your system ... May be work.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**
Add this script at bottom of podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.aggregate_targets.each do |target|
    copy_pods_resources_path = "Pods/Target Support Files/#{target.name}/#{target.name}-resources.sh"
    string_to_replace = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}"'
    assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments = '--compile "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH}" --app-icon "${ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME}" --output-partial-info-plist "${BUILD_DIR}/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist"'
    text = File.read(copy_pods_resources_path)
    new_contents = text.gsub(string_to_replace, assets_compile_with_app_icon_arguments)
    File.open(copy_pods_resources_path, "w") {|file| file.puts new_contents }
end 
end
```